# Laravel "nested" with()

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 models: `Article`, `Comment`, `Reaction`.

Each article has many comments, and each comment has many reactions:

**App\Article:**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**App\Comment:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    public function reactions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reactions');
    }
}
```

**App\Reaction:**

```
class Reaction extends Model
{
    public function comment() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

In my `ArticleController@index` I want to fetch comments and their reactions:

**ArticleController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::with('comments')
                ->select('articles.*')
                ->leftjoin('comments', 'comments.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                ->get();

    return view('wiki')->withArticles($articles);
}
```

I can loop through the comments (`$article->comments`), however I'm not sure how to do a `with('reactions')` for the comments? i.e.,

```
@foreach($article->comments as $comment)
    @foreach($comment->reactions)
        // something like this...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use the `with` method? You can just as easily get all the articles using `Articles::all();`

Comment: @Adherence - didn't know it joined them automatically with the `all()` method, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `Nested Eager Loading`

```
$article = Article::with('comments.reactions')
                ->leftjoin('comments', 'comments.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                ->select('articles.*')
                ->get();
```

Comment: What about the reactions?

Comment: @frosty check now,added articles by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way

**ArticleController:**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::with('comments')
                    ->select('articles.*')
                    ->get();

        return view('wiki')->withArticles($articles);
    }
```

**App\Article:**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->with('reactions');
    }
}
```

**App\Comment:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    public function reactions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reactions');
    }
}
```